# Problems with signing emails with OpenDKIM

Tags: postfix, email-server, dkim, opendkim

I've installed `OpenDKIM` to sign the outgoing emails sent from `Postfix` mail server following this guidelines:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM
- https://www.exratione.com/2014/07/setting-up-spf-and-dkim-for-an-ubuntu-1404-mail-server/

After following them, I've checked the DKIM Key [here](https://protodave.com/tools/dkim-key-checker/) and it successfully finds a DKIM key with the provided selector. But still the emails are not being signed properly with the private key. After troubleshooting I find that the `OpenDKIM` process is not running in the server.

Then I tried to run the process manually:

```
sudo service opendkim start
```

which results in following error:

```
Starting OpenDKIM: opendkim: /etc/opendkim.conf: /etc/postfix/dkim.key can be read or written by other users opendkim.
```

Before that I'd changed the permissions of `dkim.key` file to 755 and changed the ownership of the file to the user opendkim from the group opendkim:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/postfix/dkim.key

sudo chown opendkim:opendkim /etc/postfix/dkim.key
```

**How can I run the process opendkim?**

Comment: mine's perms are:

    -rw------- opendkim opendkim

Comment: You should set the `UserID` option in `opendkim.conf` correctly. It seems to be set to `postfix` by default. 0400 is a reasonable permission setting for the private key that is not supposed to be changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opendkim error loading key](https://serverfault.com/questions/909125/opendkim-error-loading-key)