# Opendkim can not find domain key (No such file or directory)

Tags: postfix, opendkim, ubuntu-22.04

I am building a mailserver with postfix, dovecot and opendkim using Ubuntu 22 LTS. Everything worked fine in my dev environment (same setup as far as I checked), but when I deployed it live, opendkim can not find the key for my domain.

In mail.log I found these errors:

```
Dec 27 19:47:28 mail opendkim[45695]: can't load key from /etc/opendkim/keys/my.domain/default.private": No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:47:28 mail opendkim[45695]: 65291400A5: error loading key 'default._domainkey.my.domain'
```

I double checked that the file exists, and even tried `chmod -R 777 /etc/opendkim/keys` just to be sure that I am not having permission issues, but it did not work. I even logged in a vmail user, and checked that I can read this file with any user (just testing).

My main.cf postfix configuration is

```
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

/etc/default/opendkim

```
RUNDIR=/run/opendkim
SOCKET="local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock"
USER=opendkim
GROUP=opendkim
PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/$NAME.pid
EXTRAAFTER=
```

/etc/opendkim.conf

```
Syslog          yes
SyslogSuccess       yes
LogWhy          yes

Canonicalization    relaxed/simple
Mode            sv
SubDomains      no
OversignHeaders     From
AutoRestart         yes
AutoRestartRate     10/1M
Background          yes
DNSTimeout          5
SignatureAlgorithm  rsa-sha256

UserID          opendkim
UMask           007
Socket          local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
PidFile         /run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
TrustAnchorFile     /usr/share/dns/root.key
KeyTable           refile:/etc/opendkim/key.table
SigningTable       refile:/etc/opendkim/signing.table
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the first error from the mail.log file, you will see that there is a trailing `"`. There is no corresponding opening `"`.

You therefore have an error in either `/etc/opendkim/key.table` or `/etc/opendkim/signing.table`

If you look in both of those files, you will probably see a trailing `"`. Just remove it & restart.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly the error. A trailing " in `/etc/opendkim/key.table` file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post [opendkim error loading key](https://serverfault.com/questions/909125/opendkim-error-loading-key)
OpenDKIM might not like such open permissions as they are unsafe.
The post includes code on how to test keys

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but unfortunatelly that did not work. I double checked file permissions like some of the answers in that question, but still got the same error.

Comment: @AmauriGabriel login as the opendkim user & try, it may be the permissions on `/etc/opendkim` are wrong, or perhaps you have a hidden character in the path.

Comment: @Bib3 I tested and the file is accessible. `opendkim@mail:~$ cat /etc/opendkim/keys/mydomain/default.private` returns the private key